# Slack API remove bot from channel

Tags: api, slack, slack-api

I'd like to remove a slack bot from a channel using slack's API.
I've tried [channels.kick](https://api.slack.com/methods/channels.kick) but ofcourse, a bot is not a user so it can't be deleted that way. I haven't found any solutions so far on the interwet or on Slacks API documentation.

Comment: I don't know who voted to close and why, but in my opinion this is a legit programming question about how to use the Slack API.

Answer (score 0):

You are not correct. You can remove a bot user from a public channel or private channel using API methods just fine. I just tested it on a private channel to confirm.

So there must be another reason why this does not work for you. Please check if any of these reasons below apply to your case. Also, please provide the error message you are getting from the API, as that would greatly help to identify the reason.

Here are some potential reasons why kicking a bot user might not work for you:

- **wrong method**: channels.kick only works for public channel, use groups.kick for private channels.
- **wrong token**: bot tokens can not use the kick methods. You need to use a user access token to invoke that API method. (you would get the `user_is_bot` error)
- **trying to remove oneself**: a user can not kick himself. (you would get the `cant_kick_self` error)
- **not using channel IDs**: the kick methods require you to provide a channel ID, the name will not work. (you would get the `channel_not_found` error)

Based on your question I would assume you are getting the `user_is_bot` error, which let you to assume (incorrectly) that you can't kick a bot. In that case the solution would be to use a user token (not a bot token) to execute the method.

Comment: Thanks, when I try to remove the bot I use the `OAuth Access Token` of my app. The API docs state ` 
Authentication token.
Requires scope: channels:write` (https://api.slack.com/methods/channels.kick), that's why I thought I should use my app's token. But if I understand correctly I should use the token of my user?

Comment: I got this response from slack: `object(stdClass)#3 (2) {
  ["ok"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["error"]=>
  string(14) "user_not_found"
}` when calling https://slack.com/api/channels.kick

Comment: app token is fine. Based on your error: are you sure you use the correct user ID in `channels.kick`? you get the user ID of the bot user from `users.list`.